# VS 2019 Remote Linux doesn't copy all headers files

Tags: linux, visual-studio, raspberry-pi

I have a  problem when I tried to use VS 2019 to remote develop on raspberry pi.
The headers file don't copy to the windows machine, even the most elemental like stdio.h
When i tried to force an update in Tools/Options/Cross Plataform/Connection Manager/Remote Headers IntelliSense Manager/Update, the update never suceded and I received differentes errors likes this one :

**An error has occurred. Timed out executing command 'realpath -m -L ~', waited for 15000.1469ms. Please see C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\vslinux_header_update_log.txt for more information. Please see https://aka.ms/AA23jat for troubleshooting*.*

Going to the page above doesn't provide any help.

I also tried to manually copy the files in /usr/include from raspberry, but it looks that windows doesn't like the directory structure because some headers appear but others not

I reinstall VS 20199 twice but the error continue
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and VS was not guilty. The timeout was caused by an intermitent failure in the WiFi, I tried with an eth connection and the problem disappear.